# Retrieve property send by Producer Template in camel end point

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am developing spring boot application in which I am using apche camel I want to generate dynamic file url. I am using sendBodyAndProperty method from which i am passing body and property but i am facing unknown function Id error.

```
producerTemplate.sendBodyAndProperty("direct:firstRout", 
            user.toString(), "Id", 
            user.getId() + ".json");
```

Here Id is key and user.getId() is value

Route Builder code

```
@Component
public class CamelComponent extends RouteBuilder{

    public static String fileName;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {      
        from("direct:firstRoute").convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("file:///D:/test/?fileName=${Id}"));
    }   
}
```

Here is stack trace

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[file:///D:/test/?fileName=${Id}] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[direct:firstRoute]] -> [ConvertBodyTo[ja... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: file:///D:/test/?fileName=%24%7BId%7D due to: Unknown function: Id at location 0
${Id}
*

    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1831) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:136) ~[camel-spring-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:174) ~[camel-spring-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.igtb.App.main(App.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[file:///D:/test/?fileName=${Id}] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[direct:firstRoute]] -> [ConvertBodyTo[ja... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: file:///D:/test/?fileName=%24%7BId%7D due to: Unknown function: Id at location 0
${Id}
*

    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1298) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1148) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3727) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3441) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:208) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3245) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3268) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3245) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3168) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:133) ~[camel-spring-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: file:///D:/test/?fileName=%24%7BId%7D due to: Unknown function: Id at location 0
${Id}
*

    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:763) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:219) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:115) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:121) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:549) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:510) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:226) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1295) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: Unknown function: Id at location 0
${Id}
*

    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.parseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:67) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleLanguage.createExpression(SimpleLanguage.java:186) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileEndpoint.createFileLanguageExpression(GenericFileEndpoint.java:1298) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileEndpoint.setFileName(GenericFileEndpoint.java:584) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:568) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:645) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:497) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:507) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.setProperties(EndpointHelper.java:254) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:309) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:297) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileComponent.createEndpoint(GenericFileComponent.java:67) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileComponent.createEndpoint(GenericFileComponent.java:37) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:126) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:716) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleParserException: Unknown function: Id
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createSimpleExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:256) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:58) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart.doCreateLiteralExpression(SimpleFunctionStart.java:68) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart.createExpression(SimpleFunctionStart.java:58) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.createExpressions(SimpleExpressionParser.java:174) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:97) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.parseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:64) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
@Component
public class CamelComponent extends RouteBuilder{

    public static String fileName;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {      
        from("direct:firstRoute").convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("file:///D:/test/?fileName=${exchangeProperty.Id}"));
    }   
}
```

The way you access the property is using `exchangeProperty`.